# WebBrowser Control auto size the full web page

Tags: vb.net, web, browser, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to make a WebBrowser Control auto size the full web page?
Like this:

[image]

```
    Public Class Form1
     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "Web Browser"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoBack()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoForward()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.pt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I just have that code...
where i should put the code?

Comment: did you read this msdn [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da05f594-3151-40a4-83ed-9d9a859fe449/vbnet-webbrowser-control-auto-size-full-screen) completely ?

Comment: yes but i don't undearstand what i need to do...

Comment: so just see [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?626738-RESOLVED-AutoSize-WebBrowser-control) or provide your code behind ??

Comment: the code is up here now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first you have to put a `TimerControl` in your `form`
- and rest is given below

  Public Class Form1

  ```
      Dim pswaHeight As Object
      Dim pswaWidth As Object
      Dim pswaHeightInt As Integer
      Dim pswaWidthInt As Integer

      Private Enum Exec
          OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM = 63
      End Enum

      Private Enum execOpt
          OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT = 0
          OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
          OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
          OLECMDEXECOPT_SHOWHELP = 3
      End Enum
      Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

          pswaHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
          pswaWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
          pswaHeightInt = CInt(pswaHeight)
          pswaWidthInt = CInt(pswaWidth)

          Me.Text = "Web Browser"

      End Sub

      Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
          Timer1.Start()
      End Sub

      Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick


          If WebBrowser1.Width > Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 5.6) And WebBrowser1.Width < Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 2.97) Or WebBrowser1.Height > Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 3.0) And WebBrowser1.Height < Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 2.4) Then
              Try
                  Dim Res As Object = Nothing
                  Dim MyWeb As Object
                  MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
                  MyWeb.ExecWB(Exec.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, execOpt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 40, IntPtr.Zero)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MsgBox(ex.Message)
              End Try
          End If

          If WebBrowser1.Width > Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 2.97) And WebBrowser1.Width < Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 2.58) Or WebBrowser1.Height > Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 2.4) And WebBrowser1.Height < Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 2.13) Then
              Try
                  Dim Res As Object = Nothing
                  Dim MyWeb As Object
                  MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
                  MyWeb.ExecWB(Exec.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, execOpt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 50, IntPtr.Zero)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MsgBox(ex.Message)
              End Try
          End If

          If WebBrowser1.Width > Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 2.58) And WebBrowser1.Width < Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 2.23) Or WebBrowser1.Height > Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 2.13) And WebBrowser1.Height < Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.85) Then
              Try
                  Dim Res As Object = Nothing
                  Dim MyWeb As Object
                  MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
                  MyWeb.ExecWB(Exec.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, execOpt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 60, IntPtr.Zero)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MsgBox(ex.Message)
              End Try
          End If

          If WebBrowser1.Width > Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 2.23) And WebBrowser1.Width < Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 1.89) Or WebBrowser1.Height > Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.85) And WebBrowser1.Height < Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.64) Then
              Try
                  Dim Res As Object = Nothing
                  Dim MyWeb As Object
                  MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
                  MyWeb.ExecWB(Exec.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, execOpt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 70, IntPtr.Zero)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MsgBox(ex.Message)
              End Try
          End If

          If WebBrowser1.Width > Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 1.89) And WebBrowser1.Width < Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 1.6) Or WebBrowser1.Height > Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.64) And WebBrowser1.Height < Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.53) Then
              Try
                  Dim Res As Object = Nothing
                  Dim MyWeb As Object
                  MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
                  MyWeb.ExecWB(Exec.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, execOpt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 80, IntPtr.Zero)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MsgBox(ex.Message)
              End Try
          End If

          If WebBrowser1.Width > Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 1.6) And WebBrowser1.Width < Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 1.2) Or WebBrowser1.Height > Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.53) And WebBrowser1.Height < Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.16) Then
              Try
                  Dim Res As Object = Nothing
                  Dim MyWeb As Object
                  MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
                  MyWeb.ExecWB(Exec.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, execOpt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 90, IntPtr.Zero)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MsgBox(ex.Message)
              End Try
          End If

          If WebBrowser1.Width > Math.Round(pswaWidthInt / 1.2) AndAlso WebBrowser1.Height > Math.Round(pswaHeightInt / 1.16) Then
              Try
                  Dim Res As Object = Nothing
                  Dim MyWeb As Object
                  MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
                  MyWeb.ExecWB(Exec.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, execOpt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 100, IntPtr.Zero)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MsgBox(ex.Message)
              End Try
          End If
      End Sub


   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


      WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
  End Sub
  Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      WebBrowser1.GoBack()
  End Sub
  Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
      WebBrowser1.GoForward()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
      WebBrowser1.Refresh()
  End Sub
  Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
      WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.pt")
  End Sub
      End Class
  ```

Comment: Thank you, but i can't scrolling down and up?

Comment: @Jossez put `webbrowser` control inside a `TabControl`

Answer (score 0):

In the TabControls first Tab set the text to be the URL address (or blank spaces) and pad it with extra spaces to fit the width of the form.
That way it looks like the address bar of your browser (If you want it).

Also make sure you set "Modifiers" to Public on all controls which you want to control via code external to the form.

Most important: Do not use "My.settings" within the form if it is not the form first loaded (main loaded form or module).
Always store settings within the first loaded module form along with
"My.Settings.Save". Any attempt to save settings in anything bu main mofule/form causes corruption in your "My.Settings" (something I learned by accident and taken 3 months to resolve reason corruption was occuring).